# GetExternalLoginInfoAsync always NULL for google login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, google-signin

I have the Client Id and secret already for Google Authentication. After selecting account in google to use to login, GetExternalLoginInfoAsync always returns null. I have tried to create new project to see if there's an issue with google however it turns out I can login successfully to my newly created project but I can't do it in my existing project.

I am able to select account in google to use like this screenshot below and after selecting, I still got NULL returns for GetExternalLoginInfoAsync. Is there anything else I need to check?

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us your code and explain what's not working in the code.

Comment: I've used the codes generated in mvc asp.net and only add the client id and secret into Startup.Auth.cs for google authentication

Comment: So given the code you've provided I should be able to replicate your issue? If not, you need to provide a [mcve].